# How to precompile WCF code and then host it on IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

How do you precompile WCF code so that the WCF code can't be seen by anyone who has access to the WCF code.

it's possible to this with ASP.NET code by using the "precompilation" feature. basically, what the precompilation feature does is enable the developper to deploy "binaries" to IIS instead of a folder containing source code.
can this be done with WCF too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be confused about something.

A WCF project is always "pre-compiled", unless you go out of your way to be unusual. The source files do not need to be deployed in order for the service to operate.

What leads you to believe that your source code needs to be deployed?

Comment: John is right. A WCF application is not deployed with source code as ASP.NET web forms website projects used to be...

Comment: Thanks John. I think I see where I got confused. just the .dll needs to be deployed. and from the answers of other people, it could (.dll) be obfuscated if wanted. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an obfuscator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why people are DVing your post as this is a legitimate question. However what you are actually looking for is source code protection not pre-compilation.

Source code protection can be many faceted to be effective however I routinely state it's generally worthless as you will spend alot of time and money for a very intangible benefit. If your product is based on a brand new algorithm that has true commercial value C# is definitely not the optimal language to develop that module in.

There are posts on here about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402430/how-do-i-use-net-without-loss-of-control-over-intellectual-property being on of them. It's also possible this question will be closed as a duplicate.